# How to create Seller and secret identifier for Google Wallet?

Tags: android-pay

I am trying to create a new seller account so that I can get my seller identifier and secret identifier

In the google tutorial , there is a link to "Sign up for Wallet for digital goods (sandbox)".

https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/merchant/signup.html?pli=1

However following this link you can only subscribe as a buyer , entering a test credit card .

How can I get my seller and secret identifier?

Answer (score 0):

In the Wallet for digital goods APi documentation see the "Getting Started -> Get set up as a seller" section

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial#6